# Is Autofac IComponentContext.Resolve<Type> a service locator pattern

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

In a recent code review, I found the class resolver by IComponentContext as shown in below example:

```
using Autofac;

public class BaseClass
{
    protected IComponentContext _componentContext;
    public BaseClass(IComponentContext componentContext)
    {
        _componentContext = componentContext;
    }
}

public class MyClass1: BaseClass
{
   protected IMyClass2 _myClass2 = _componentContext.Resolve<MyClass2>();
   public void Operation1()
   {
        _myClass2.Operation2();
   }
}
```

I feel the above code is resolving MyClass2 outside of Class1() constructor. Isn't it a service locator pattern and voilating IOC?

Comment: I would say yes and yes. With Autofac you can write code at the composition root if you need a specific concrete class to be injected into a specific registration (via `.WithParameter` and the `ResolvedParameter` parameter type).

Comment: Yes, it is a smell. Seemingly someone didn't want to go through the effort of identifying dependencies in the subclasses and / or didn't want to repeatedly pass dependencies which are needed in the base class from each of the subclass constructors. Either way, we also don't want to be resolving `MyClass2` - we want to resolve an abstraction, like `IFroobWriter`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is an example of using the service locator pattern. To fix it, your `BaseClass` should take no `IComponentContext` (to ensure no other service location happens) and the `MyClass1` should take a constructor parameter of type `IMyClass2`.